# Is it possible to specify a global location for the jshint config file ( .jshintrc )?

Tags: javascript, configure, jshint

For example this can be done for a global .gitignore file used by git as follows:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile some_path
```

I have a directory in which I place my config files and would like to do this for my jshint config file as well ...